# Why worship women?

Tags: worship, women

See my question is why God allows us to worship women.
"worship women" means you are worshiping materialistic thing.

Comment: Why do you think we worship women? We may worship woman gods, but even then that is just the form we give them, and they are beyond man and woman.

Comment: Your q is very unclear.

Comment: @Prasanna R - please wait, the person should understand why it is. No one should have a doubt in Hinduism all should be cleared only then he will attain knowledge.

Comment: @PrasannaR i agree with you. This particular user is obsessed with comparing Islam’s views with Hinduism. I don’t see the reason to compare? If Islam has modesty, this mr siddiqui will ask about modesty, if Islam has degrading women, so he will ask a Q why worship women. I don’t see any connection. He is the cause of the huge discussion on meta about rape justification.

Comment: @Rahul yes i agree with you i too taught after closing.. may be i will remove the closure vote because we need to question everything then only truth willbe know or why we do some thing or why it shouldnt we do those thing.. unfortunately i cannot recall because now its reopen anyway i have voted for reopen

Comment: @Prasanna R - but the question needs clarification before reopen

Comment: One can on the other hand similarly ask - *"Why to worship Parents or a Guru? - because obviously all of them are "material things". The Real and the only Parent & Guru is the Sachchidananda-BhagvAn only, so why worship anyone who's a Human?"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know what exactly you want as a answer. Worshiping women have different aims, perspectives, purposes in different upasana or whatever you need to call them.
For e.g. the kulavarna tantra gives a lot of importance to kumari puja. There are many other vidhis and pujas which cannot be performed without a women as a kumari or sister or a wife. The Aannadakalptantra gives 4-5 verses which refer to the importance of women. (Why?) This is because:

> इमशानसाधन नात्र न चिताशवसाधनम्‌।
> योषित्पूजनमात्रेण  अन्नपूर्णा सुसिद्धिदा॥

> *Annapurna devi* does not need its *sadhaka* to go grave (*samshan*) or *Chita* to perform the *sadhana*. The *sadhana* happens through the medium of women. For *Annapurna devi*, respecting women is equivalent to perform *sadhana* of her.

Why is it not materialistic?
As far as a perticular sadhana is concern I think these verses are valid throughout, not just in the perspective of *sadhana* Annapurna.

> अथान्यत्‌ सम्प्रवक्ष्यामि श्वृणु ब्रह्मत्‌ समाहितः।
> न च योषित्समो धाता न विष्णुर्नापि छाद्धुरः:।
> स्त्रियो देवा: स्त्रिय: प्राणा स्त्रिय एव विभूषणस्‌ ।
> स्त्रीसज्धिना सदा भांव्यमन्यथा न प्रसीदति।
> क्षुब्धायां योषिति क्षुब्धा सदा देवी न संशय: ॥

> Even *Bhramha*, *Vishnu* and *Mahesh* are not equal to women. Women is equivalent to god, she is pran (life), she is *"vibushan"*. Always imagine god in women, otherwise Annapurna devi does not become happy. If women becomes *क्षुब्ध* which means *Ashant* or "not calm-angry", it gets reflected in Annapurna as well. (It means devi also becomes angry on the sadhaka)