# Why are 'HUMAN BEINGS' different, according to Hindu Philosophy?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, human, consciousness, darshan

All of us inherently recognise the concept of fundamental human dignity - that **human beings are** **BORN FREE and EQUAL**. But why are they, what is its philosophical basis in HINDUISM?

What is the basis of '**human dignity**' that separates us from all other living beings and non-living beings, such that a human being's life is obviously **more important than that of a rat, or a robot**?

Does it have something to do with 'intelligence' or 'free will'? If so, how exactly?
Because a lot of human beings do not possess free will and intelligence.

Please provide your answers based on **SCRIPTURES**.

Comment: *“But why are they”* - simply because of ego and a superiority complex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the characteristics of a human being?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23971/what-are-the-characteristics-of-a-human-being)

Comment: [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44408/are-humans-superior-to-other-animals-according-to-vedas-bhagavad-gita-and-upani) may be useful as well.

Comment: @Adiyarkku so you're saying that human beings AREN'T born free and equal - you're entitled to your opinion but that's extremely stupid, and that's not exactly the question I asked.

Comment: @CDR thanks for the effort, but no, the questions linked DO NOT answer the question, which is - why are human beings born free and equal. Even if a human being does not possess the qualities mentioned in these answers - like a newborn - we still have an inherent understanding of why their life is worth more than that of an animal. WHY IS THAT?

Comment: Oh, I see. Not sure how to answer that, then.

Comment: @CDR no worries