# Notion of "Patni Parameshvari (Wife is the Supreme Goddess)" - found in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, women, marriage, men

Similar to this question where I ask: [Is notion of Pati - Parameśvara (husband is the Supreme Lord) based on scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48035/is-notion-of-pati-parame%c5%9bvara-husband-is-the-supreme-lord-based-on-scripture)

Does canonical texts enjoin: Patnī Parameśvarī (पत्नी परमेश्वरी) - i.e., A Wife is equivalent to the Supreme Goddess to her Husband?

**Which scriptures have the notion of Wife being the Supreme Goddess (Patnī Parameśvarī) for a husband?**

Please include multiple references from different scriptures (if possible), along with the original Sanskrit verses too.

Comment: Tantras show highest degree of respect towards women. However notations like "patni parameshwari" is not used. See [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44406/21353) for instance. In many tantra sadhanas, women are worshiped(?) as if mother/devi/godess.

Comment: Proxy is TOTALLY INCORRECT. Sadhna =/= life. **Tantrik gurus in ALL SECTS like Nath, Kaul, Aghori, Kapalik, Banglamukhi etc. are ALL MEN who even avoid contact with women** ANNADAKALPA TANTRA =/= SHRUTI!! IT IS NOT MENTIONED IN ANY LIST OF 64 TANTRAS !!! It is not accepted. Tantras say a woman has to obey her husband and beating is allowed (though it may not be considered good everywhere).  **E.G., Mahanirvan T talks about controlling women - "When women become difficult of control, heartless and quarrelsome, and calumniators of their husbands, then know that the Kali Age has become strong"**

Comment: Same Tantra also agrees that with other scriptures **"For women there is no necessity to go on pilgrimage, to fast, or to do other like acts, nor is there any need to perform any devotion except that which consists in the service of their husband  For a woman
her husband is a place of pilgrimage, the performance of penance, the giving of alms, the carrying out of vows, and her spiritual teacher. Therefore should a woman devote herself to the service of her husband with her whole self "** There are entire sections on this. And there is toooo much more info on this in 64 tantra shruti texts !!!